# Entropy of a gas having fixed volume

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

Gases have particles which always move randomly. Can certain amount of gas enclosed in a container have zero entropy?

Comment: Do you know the mathematical definition of entropy and the law of thermodynamics referring to absolute zero? This should clearly answer your question if you search through Wikipedia.

Comment: But at absolute zero temperature , it would turn into solid phase.

Comment: Please read this page     https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bose%E2%80%93Einstein_condensate

Answer (score 0):

No, a certain amount of gas enclosed in a container cannot have zero entropy. More specifically, the gas would have zero entropy at temperature = 0K, however 0K is unable to be reached (one cannot reach absolute zero).